# ASP.NET : SqlDataSource insert - identity parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I have an asp.net application in which I am inserting into an sql table using a GridView linked to an SqlDataSource. The problem is that I do not know the 'Identity' parameter to use on insertion. The 'Identity' column should be automatically incrementing, however upon inserting, I get an exception that the Identity param must not be null. How do I either craft the insert statement so that this works or how do I get the next correct identity # to specify? Thanks.

Here is my SqlDataSource code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VehiclesSqlDS" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RamRideOpsConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Vehicles]" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Vehicles] ([Identity], [CarNum], [MaxPassengers], [Status], [CurrPassengers], [StartAdd], [EndAdd], [AvgRideTime], [numRides]) VALUES (@Identity, @CarNum, @MaxPassengers, @Status, @CurrPassengers, @StartAdd, @EndAdd, @AvgRideTime, @numRides)" 
        OnInserting="VehiclesSqlDS_Insert"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">         
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Identity" Type="Int32 "/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CarNum" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="MaxPassengers" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="3" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" DefaultValue="Ready" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CurrPassengers" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StartAdd" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EndAdd" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Time" Name="AvgRideTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="numRides" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        </InsertParameters>        
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set parameter direction to OUTPut, to get the identity value. from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/z72eefad.aspx)

and  handle the onInserted event to get, the identity value

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        string sID = e.Command.Parameters["@Identity"].Value.ToString();
       //Display new ID

    }
```

you can try like this.

```
<asp:sqlDataSource ID="Datasource" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID"

  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Employees(LastName, FirstName) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName); 
                 SELECT @EmpID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE Employees SET LastName=@LastName, FirstName=@FirstName 
                   WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID"
  DeleteCommand="DELETE Employees WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID"

  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
  OnInserted="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource_OnInserted"
  RunAt="server">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </SelectParameters>

  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Direction="Output" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </InsertParameters>

</asp:sqlDataSource>
```

Comment: This seems correct but I am still getting the null exception, any idea why this might be? [It appears that SCOPE_IDENTITY is null]

Comment: you debugged it ? you follow the MSDN links. may be it will help ful

Comment: Yeah, debugged, looked at the link, and even just put it back the way it was and picked a random default value that should have worked for one insert, but it always gives me the null error..

Comment: Wow, thank you all for the help.. as it turns out this problem had an easier solution that originally expected. The Identity setting in the db got turned off somehow.. Solution: turn it back on. ARG.. Thanks anyway! ( ;

Answer (score 1):

You should omit the Identity column from the insert statement.  Only include the data columns.  The Sql Server will create the auto-increment then.

```
INSERT INTO [Vehicles] ([CarNum], [MaxPassengers], [Status], [CurrPassengers], [StartAdd], [EndAdd], [AvgRideTime], [numRides]) VALUES (@CarNum, @MaxPassengers, @Status, @CurrPassengers, @StartAdd, @EndAdd, @AvgRideTime, @numRides)
```

Comment: That would be the obvious solution, but unfortunately, as I said I get the following exception: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Identity', table 'CWIS29RamRideOps.dbo.Vehicles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 1):

Ever Present, that is assuming that Identity is an auto-incremeneted column. It could just be a regular column.

You need to somehow retrieve the latest Identity first before trying to insert.

Alternatively you could write a trigger on the database that automatically updates the Identity column when a new item is added.

Comment: I tried retrieving the previous identity, which was simple enough, but in this particular table, it is not uncommon for it to be empty, then on the first insert I have no previous entry to start with, especially since the table identity numbers do not reset to 1. I am somewhat new to asp.net and sql, do you have any good resources on writing triggers? That may do the trick..

Answer (score 1):

These snippets may help:

```
<InsertParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="SalesRepID" Type="Int32" />
   ...more params

    <asp:Parameter Name="QuoteID" Type="Int32" Direction="Output" />            
</InsertParameters>
```

Note the second command added

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [MyTable] (fields); SET @QuoteID = Scope_Identity();"
```

Comment: This sure looks like the correct way to do it, but for some reason I am still getting the same error that Identity cannot be null. Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your database table isn't constructed to automatically increment the ID.

Comment: Yup, you got it, stupid mistake, somehow got turned off. Thanks.